# (iOS) IAP working but missing in client's Beta using Fabric

Tags: ios, in-app-purchase, google-fabric

I' working on an (ancient) app from a client. The app have been on the App Store for many years and it has working in-app purchases currently.

I'm updating this app and everything IAP related seems to work ok but when I send a beta to my client's test accounts using Crashlytics, the app works ok but the IAP are unavailable for them. Is there any configuration I should do in order to make the IAP working?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, I've managed to make it work. I needed to create good ol' provisioning profiles at Apple Dev Center and set Xcode back to manual mode. Once I set distribution provisioning for release builds, everything worked as it should.

I was under the impression that Crashlytics would make everything for me when Xcode was set on automatic mode but it seems that the IAP are more tricky.

Answer (score 0):

Mike from Fabric here. There are many different things you need to do in order to allow for IAP testing. Apple's [documentation](https://developer.apple.com/library/content/technotes/tn2259/_index.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/DTS40009578-CH1-CERTIFICATES__IDENTIFIERS___PROFILES) is good on this, but a few key points from the doc.

To test in-app purchase, you need to create products to purchase and test accounts to make the purchases. iTunes Connect allows you to create and manage in-app purchases and test user accounts. You must complete the following steps in iTunes Connect:

**Create test user accounts:**  Apple provides a testing environment, called the sandbox, which allows you to test your in-app purchases without incurring any financial charges. The sandbox environment uses special test user accounts rather than your regular iTunes Connect accounts to test in-app purchase. See Sandbox Testers in the iTunes Connect Developer Guide for more information about creating test user accounts.

**Note:** You can use the same test user accounts to test both your iOS, macOS, and tvOS applications. Each in-app purchase test user account is tied to one and only one email address. As such, you cannot reuse an existing email address with another test user account.

**To Test your application in the sandbox environment:**

1) Sign out of the Store in the Settings application on your testing device.

2) Set the run destination of your application to an iOS or tvOS Device in Xcode.

3) Build and run your application from Xcode.

**Important:** Use your test user account when prompted by StoreKit to confirm a purchase from within your application.
StoreKit connects to the sandbox environment when you launch your application from Xcode, from your test device (iOS and tvOS), or from the Finder (macOS). It connects to a production environment for applications that were downloaded from the App Store. You must not use your test user account to sign into the production environment. This will result in your test user account becoming invalid. Invalid test accounts cannot be used to test in-app purchase again.

Comment: Thanks Mike but that's not the problem. The problem is the IAPs are not available in client's devices. We have many sandbox accounts to test the purchases but it seems the items are not appearing in beta devices. As I told, the IAPs are currently working since it's a new version of an old app. I can't track the real apple response to products availability since it works properly in my own devices. Probably it's not Fabric related but I just wanted to ask just in case I've missed any requested step with provisioning, certificates and so.

Comment: I'm using Xcode automatic signing. Is it possible this is messing with the developer/distribution provisionings? It used to be signed as Distribution for Ad-Hoc releases before if I recall correctly

Comment: It's possible that Automatic signing is causing the issue, but I agree that this is an Apple issue most likely. I'll admit to not being an expert on IAP, but I don't think the issue is a Fabric config.